# Analogue camera: exposure counter is broken?

Tags: exposure, camera

I bought an analogue camera (Pentax MZ-50) and every time I turn on/ off the camera the exposure counter goes one up, meaning the frames are being unused as I am not taking any photos. How is it possible the counter is counting a frame when I am not depressing the shutter release button?

Comment: It is a **film** camera. It uses film to capture images on a film coated with a light sensitive silver halide coating.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_film  Are there any other problems that may be associated with the electronics, is it otherwise functioning properly?

Comment: When this happens, does the camera actually take a picture and/or cycle the mirror or shutter? Is the film actually being advanced when the exposure counter is increased?